# scala - how to concatenate columns of a DataFrame with concat_ws?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to concatenate columns of my Dataframe. I wrote a Udf to achieve that but as I can see `concat_ws` expects columns while I'm passing it `Array[String]`. How should I pass columns of my DataFrame correctly?

```
val columns = salesDF.columns
val concatColumns = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => arr.mkString(" "))

salesDF.select(concat_ws(",", concatColumns(columns)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will just need to pass the selection as an `Array[Column]`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,concat_ws}

val selection = salesDF.columns.map(col)
salesDF.select(concat_ws(",", selection : _*))
```